# How to round down integer to all zeros behind first number

Tags: javascript

For example, I need to round number `6588 => 6000` , `1285000 => 1000000`

I can't find any `Math.ceil` , `Math.floor` methods that can achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide by the highest power of ten, floor it, then multiply back by the highest power of ten. Some other answers are manipulating string, but IMO this is the simplest and easiest to read code. Like this:

```js
function roundDown(num) {
    let powerOfTen = num.toString().length - 1;
    num /= (10**powerOfTen);
    return Math.floor(num) * (10**powerOfTen);
}

console.log(roundDown(6588))    // => 6000
console.log(roundDown(1285000)) // => 1000000
```

This is roughly the same procedure that `Math.floor()` uses, as described [in this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor);

Answer (score 1):

another variant is just work on string level, instead of numbers to avoid any floating point problems

```js
 function roundToFirst(n) {
  return (''+n).split('').map((c, i) => i > 0 ? '0' : c).join('');
 }
 
 console.log(roundToFirst(6588)); // 6000
 console.log(roundToFirst(1285000)); // 1000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your number to a string and simply append zeros to match the number's length.

```js
const roundDown = (num) => {
  num = num.toString();
  return (num[0] + new Array(num.length).join('0'));
}

console.log(roundDown(6588))
console.log(roundDown(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

A short and easy way is to take the first digit and `padEnd` the rest

```js
const roundDown = num => {
  num = String(num)
  return +num[0].padEnd(num.length, "0")
}

console.log(roundDown(6588))
console.log(roundDown(1285000))
```

#### References

[padEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd)